# Why does my Bootstrap 3.1.1 'Collapse' element automatically close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having trouble with my mobile menu/navbar.  I created a 'Sign in' button that drops down with a log in form using collapse.js that's provided by Bootstrap.  My div pulls down and collapses perfectly.  However, for whatever reason it automatically collapses back up whenever you click on the username or password text box fields.  Any idea why this is happening?

Here's a link to the jsfiddle to demonstrate this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/65KdX/2/

Here is the section of code that is for the navbar:

```
<!-- Begin Navbar items -->
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "mainNavbarInfo">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "active"><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home </a> </li>
          <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> SLO Generator </a> </li>
          <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> SLO Tutorial </a> </li>
          <li><a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Sign Up  </a></li>

          <li data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#signInFormCollapseMobile" class = "visible-xs">
            <a href = "#"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Sign In<div class = "collapse signInFormCollapse" id = "signInFormCollapseMobile" style = "position: relative;"></a>
              <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" id = "signInFormMobile">
                  <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 10px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" placeholder = "Username"/>
                  <br><input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" placeholder = "Password"/>
                  <br><input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                  <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>

                  <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
       </ul>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `form` is nested within that `<li>` block.

If you move the `div` that contains the `form` outside the `<ul>` section, it works fine.

See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkGcR/).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!  Just to make sure I understand my mistake, the key part is having the data-target set to something on the page (an id of a div for example), but keep that div separate from the actual collapsing element (<li> in this case)?  Additionally, can that div be anywhere on the page?

Comment: To answer your first question - The problem was that the data-toggle event was set to the entire <li> element.  So that clicking on your form (which was a sub-section of your <li> element) triggered the data-toggle event causing your form to subsequently collapse.

Comment: To answer your second question - I've experimented with this in the past and it does seem that the div can go just about anywhere (And hopefully someone will correct me if I'm wrong here...).

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.  I'll keep that in mind for future development